# Excel - Convert list of values into ranges

Tags: list, excel, range, vba

Could you please let me know if the following is possible in Excel?

I have a list of numbers, ie:

```
1
2
3
4
6
7
8
9
11
14
16
17
18
```

I would like to have those number in the following format:

```
1-4, 6-9, 11, 14, 16-18
```

Please let me know if it's possible or if you have any questions.

Thank you

M

Comment: Your desired output has no discernable pattern, so I'm going to say "no" it's not possible. Of course, if you explained the pattern that would help.

Comment: The patter is to check if the numbers are in order. If there is a missing number the new range would be created. For example 1 2 3 4 6 7 9 11 would create 1-4, 6-7,9, 11.

Comment: Ok, I see that now. So, do you want the output in one cell? One cell per contiguous grouping. We aren't mind readers, so try to read your question as if you were  somebody else.

Comment: Oh sorry. I would like each range to be in separate cell. Thank you

Comment: Are you looking for a VBA solution (almost trivial) or a spreadsheet formula approach (considerably harder though doable)? Also -- what have you tried? Stack Overflow is primarily a site which helps people with problems they encounter in their code rather than a free coding service which writes code to specification.

Comment: To be honest I'm pretty much stuck. Any solution would be helpful. I'm not good with VBA but if you point me in right direction I'll see if I can work it out myself.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to loop through the numbers and with each new number either extend the current range or start a new range. One possible implementation is as follows:

```
Sub GroupInRanges():
    Dim S As Range, R As Range
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, n As Long
    Dim num As Long, startNum As Long, endNum As Long

    Set S = Application.InputBox("Select range containing numbers", Type:=8)
    Set R = Application.InputBox("Select first cell of output range", Type:=8)
    n = S.Cells.Count

    startNum = S.Cells(1).Value
    endNum = startNum
    For i = 1 To n
        num = S.Cells(i).Value
        If num <= endNum + 1 Then
            'extend current number range
            endNum = num
        Else
            'process the just-completed data range
            R.Offset(j).Value = IIf(startNum < endNum, startNum & "-" & endNum, endNum)
            j = j + 1
            startNum = num 'starts a new number range
            endNum = startNum
        End If
    Next i

    'process final range
    R.Offset(j).Value = IIf(startNum < endNum, startNum & "-" & endNum, endNum)
End Sub
```

The cells in the target range should be formatted as text, otherwise Excel will e.g. interpret `1-4` as `4-Jan`.